# T-SQL Select null values from join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Essentially I want to select data from the left table (BO_HRO) that either has a matching row with 0's in both columns or when the row doesn't exist in the right table (BO_HRO_EXT).

However, the query listed below works how left joins do and returns all rows from the left table whether they exist in the right table or not.

```
SELECT preventable, warrantable 

FROM BO_HRO LEFT JOIN BO_HRO_EXT
ON BO_HRO.RO_NO = BO_HRO_EXT.RO_NO AND
(preventable = 0 OR preventable IS NULL) AND
(warrantable = 0 OR warrantable IS NULL)
```

I have looked through several solutions and either they don't quite fit my scenario or they don't work in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please give this a try:

```
SELECT 
    preventable, 
    warrantable 
FROM 
    BO_HRO 
    LEFT JOIN BO_HRO_EXT ON BO_HRO.RO_NO = BO_HRO_EXT.RO_NO 
WHERE 
    (preventable = 0 AND warrantable = 0 )
    OR (BO_HRO_EXT.RO_NO IS NULL)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. Will accept as answer when answer delay expires.

Answer (score 1):

"It is very important to understand that, with outer joins, the ON and WHERE clauses play
very different roles, and therefore, they aren’t interchangeable. The WHERE clause still plays a
simple filtering role—namely, it keeps true cases and discards false and unknown cases.
Use something like this and use predicates in where clause.
However, the ON clause doesn’t play a simple filtering role; rather, it’s more a matching
role. In other words, a row in the preserved side will be returned whether the ON predicate
finds a match for it or not. So the ON predicate only determines which rows from the nonpreserved
side get matched to rows from the preserved side—not whether to return the rows
from the preserved side." Exam 70-461: Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Use something like this and use predicates in where clause.

```
SELECT preventable, warrantable 

    FROM BO_HRO LEFT JOIN BO_HRO_EXT
    ON BO_HRO.RO_NO = BO_HRO_EXT.RO_NO 
    where(preventable = 0 AND warrantable = 0 )
OR (BO_HRO_EXT.RO_NO IS NULL
```